# How to remove certain records from a dataset spark java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

Is there any specific method to remove a record from a dataset on Apache Spark? Or is there any alternative to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `filter` method to produce a new dataset without those records.

Please note that datasets are immutable, so you cannot modify them (i.e. remove a record).

Answer (score 0):

DataFrames in Spark are like RDD in the sense that they’re an immutable data structure in nature. Therefore things like creating a new column or removing a row, or trying to access by index a single element within a DataFrame can’t exist, just because this kind of affectation goes against the principles of Spark's immutable RDD.

The only think you can do is to transformed it into your desired dataframe using transformation functions like filter

val df = spark.read.json("examples/src/main/test/employee.json")

// Register the DataFrame as a SQL temporary view
df.createOrReplaceTempView("employee")

val sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM employee where customer_id !=002")

Using this code you can remove the records having customer_id =002 and can write the filtered record in a file or in a table

sqlDF.createOrReplaceTempView("Employee") //create employee view

sqlDF.write.format("parquet").save("employee.parquet") //save it parquet file